# Find the previous-trial score within a nested dataframe in a loop and save as a new variable

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a dataframe that currently looks like this:

| subjectID | Trial | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 16 |
| 1 | 1 | 16 |
| 1 | 1 | 16 |
| 1 | 2 | 8 |
| 1 | 2 | 8 |
| 1 | 2 | 8 |
| 1 | 3 | 12 |
| 1 | 3 | 12 |
| 1 | 3 | 12 |
| 2 | 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 |

I need to create a new column, `Previous_Trial_Score`, that is simply the score on the last trial for each person. For example:

| subjectID | Trial | Score | Previous_Trial_Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 16 | NA |
| 1 | 1 | 16 | NA |
| 1 | 1 | 16 | NA |
| 1 | 2 | 8 | 16 |
| 1 | 2 | 8 | 16 |
| 1 | 2 | 8 | 16 |
| 1 | 3 | 12 | 8 |
| 1 | 3 | 12 | 8 |
| 1 | 3 | 12 | 8 |
| 2 | 1 | 9 | NA |
| 2 | 1 | 9 | NA |
| 2 | 1 | 9 | NA |
| 2 | 2 | 10 | 9 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 | 9 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 | 9 |

And so on. Trial 1 for each subject will always be `NA`, as there is no previous trial for that person. I am writing a for-loop to accomplish this, below:

```
for (myperson in unique(data$subjectID)){
  for (mytrial in unique(data$Trial[data$Trial>1])){

    #Specify the trial and person
    Prev_Score=as.numeric(unique(data[data$subjectID==myperson & data$Trial==mytrial-1, "Score"]))
    

    #Save it to the dataframe
    data[data$subjectID==myperson & data$Trial==mytrial,"Prev_Score"]=Prev_Score
    
    
  }
}
```

In the above loop, I had to specify `as.numeric` and `unique` to get R to return a single value properly. However, when I run the loop, I get this error:

```
Error: Assigned data `value` must be compatible with existing data.
i Error occurred for column `Prev_Score`.
x Can't convert from <double> to <logical> due to loss of precision.
* Locations: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 3...
```

Does anyone have a solution? I am open to tidyverse/dplyr work-arounds.

Comment: A hack could be `df |> group_by(subjectID) |> mutate(Previous_Trial_Score = lag(Score, 3)) |> ungroup()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do a group by summarise to get the `lag` and then do a join

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(subjectID, Trial) %>%
   summarise(Previous_Trial_Score = last(Score), .groups= 'drop_last') %>% 
   mutate(Previous_Trial_Score = lag(Previous_Trial_Score)) %>%   
   left_join(df1, .)
```

-output

```
   subjectID Trial Score Previous_Trial_Score
1          1     1    16                   NA
2          1     1    16                   NA
3          1     1    16                   NA
4          1     2     8                   16
5          1     2     8                   16
6          1     2     8                   16
7          1     3    12                    8
8          1     3    12                    8
9          1     3    12                    8
10         2     1     9                   NA
11         2     1     9                   NA
12         2     1     9                   NA
13         2     2    10                    9
14         2     2    10                    9
15         2     2    10                    9
```

---

Or slightly compact option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Previous_Trial_Score := shift(.SD[, last(Score), 
       Trial]$V1)[Trial], subjectID]
```

-output

```
> df1
    subjectID Trial Score Previous_Trial_Score
        <int> <int> <int>                <int>
 1:         1     1    16                   NA
 2:         1     1    16                   NA
 3:         1     1    16                   NA
 4:         1     2     8                   16
 5:         1     2     8                   16
 6:         1     2     8                   16
 7:         1     3    12                    8
 8:         1     3    12                    8
 9:         1     3    12                    8
10:         2     1     9                   NA
11:         2     1     9                   NA
12:         2     1     9                   NA
13:         2     2    10                    9
14:         2     2    10                    9
15:         2     2    10                    9
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(subjectID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Trial = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Score = c(16L, 16L, 16L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Comment: Worked very well, thank you! Will need to start seriously digging into dplyr for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `dplyr` option, where we just keep the unique rows with `distinct`, then get the `lag` value of `Score`, and join back to the original dataframe. However, if you have more columns in your dataframe, then @akrun provides a cleaner approach of handling the additional columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(subjectID) %>%
  mutate(Previous_Trial_Score = lag(Score)) %>% 
  left_join(df, .)
```

**Output**

```
   subjectID Trial Score Previous_Trial_Score
1          1     1    16                   NA
2          1     1    16                   NA
3          1     1    16                   NA
4          1     2     8                   16
5          1     2     8                   16
6          1     2     8                   16
7          1     3    12                    8
8          1     3    12                    8
9          1     3    12                    8
10         2     1     9                   NA
11         2     1     9                   NA
12         2     1     9                   NA
13         2     2    10                    9
14         2     2    10                    9
15         2     2    10                    9
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(subjectID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Trial = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Score = c(16L, 16L, 16L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```